# Correct gamepad for Hector_quadrotor control

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I need to run one hector_quadrotor with gazebo1.9 and I would like to control the quadrotor  using a gamepad. I am not familiar with gamepads  and need to buy one for my quadrotor application.
Thus, I was searching online for some information that indicates the type or brand of  gamepad to control the quadrotor but I couldn’t find any useful info that help me to pick the right gamepad.
I am planning on using the “longitech_gamepad.launch” for the teleoperation so it means that do I need to get a Logitech gamepad type? Or can anyone please indicate me the type of gamepad that I need to buy?

Thanks you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162591/correct-gamepad-for-hector_quadrotor-control/) by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use most gamepads with ROS (and thus, hector_quadrotor_teleop). PS3 controller, XBox controller and Logitech gamepads are notable examples, but most USB gamepads should work out of the box. You just have to start the joystick node and configure how the buttons/axes are mapped to controls similar to [logitech_gamepad.launch](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/blob/hydro-devel/hector_quadrotor_teleop/launch/logitech_gamepad.launch) in your own launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on 2014-05-08**:
Thanks a lot Stefan for your reply!